# Why can java nio only write bytes?

Tags: java, nio

Is it true that java nio can only write bytes? For instance:

```
    Path path=FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("\(a path)")
    Files.write(path, "test string".getBytes())
```

I cannot pass only a string to the second parameter of Files.write.
If this is the case, then why is it that only bytes can be written?

Comment: everything can only write bytes

Comment: Bytes are what files contain. Anything that looks like it's writing strings, is actually converting them to bytes and writing those. nio is mostly meant as a fast, efficient interface, so it makes sense that it wouldn't have those helpers.

Answer (score 3):

Another method, [`Files.write(Path,Iterable,Charset,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)), can be used to write `CharSequence`s directly (a `String` is a `CharSequence`).

> Write lines of text to a file. Each line is a char sequence and is written to the file in sequence with each line terminated by the platform's line separator, as defined by the system property `line.separator`. Characters are encoded into bytes using the specified charset.
>
> The `options` parameter specifies how the file is created or opened. If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of `0`. The method ensures that the file is closed when all lines have been written (or an I/O error or other runtime exception is thrown). If an I/O error occurs then it may do so after the file has been created or truncated, or after some bytes have been written to the file.

Java 8 added an overload that doesn't require a `Charset` and uses `UTF-8` as a default.

Java 11 added another method: [`Files.writeString(Path,CharSequence,Charset,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).

> Write a CharSequence to a file. Characters are encoded into bytes using the specified charset.
>
> All characters are written as they are, including the line separators in the char sequence. No extra characters are added.
>
> The `options` parameter specifies how the file is created or opened. If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of `0`.

This method also has an overload that doesn't require a `Charset`, using `UTF-8` as a default again.

Under the hood, however, the `CharSequence`s are converted to bytes just like Scary Wombat and yshavit mention in the question comments. The documentation of these methods even make this explicit:

> Characters are encoded into bytes using the specified charset.